# How to remove paths from tabs in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ide, tabs

Is there a way to stop the path showing in a source code tab in Visual Studio 2008?

Currently when developing an ASP.NET site, I get the path from the root plus the filename - truncated when it gets too long. So something like:

> MyDir/MyPage.aspx

for a short path and filename, or:

> MyDir/MyLong...yPage.aspx

for a longer path and filename.

I'd prefer to see just the filename (ie just MyPage.aspx), allowing more tabs to show at once and making it easier to see which files I have open without using the drop-down list or Crtl-Tab to show the full set.

In VS2005, I just get the filename - no path however long it is. Oddly in VS2003 I get the path and filename. I've scoured the options and I can't find a setting that lets me change what appears in the tabs. Searching suggests that other people have similar issues (although which version it occurs in appears to differ) but no-one could identify an option to change what appears.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get rid of the paths in the tabs (or confirm that it can't be changed to save me wasting more time searching)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tabs Studio](http://www.tabsstudio.com) add-in can remove path from tab in Visual Studio 2008.

See 
[Removing path from tab name](http://tabsstudio.wordpress.com/2009/05/07/removing-path-from-tab-name/)
blog post for the example screenshots.

Comment: @Sergey: I'm giving Tabs Studio a go, so thanks for the suggestion. With the ability to stack the tabs in multiple rows and group files with the same folder/filename into a single tab, removing the path isn't such an issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my copy of VS 2008 I just get the filename, not the path.  I wonder whether it's a "web site" vs "web application" thing.  Which one are you working in?  Can you create a project of the other type and see if it still happens?  (I'm working in a web application where I get filename-only.)

Comment: It's a web site project. Moving to a web application just to get rid of the file paths isn't an option. Currently it looks like I'm stuck with the file paths - but still looking...

Comment: I have no idea why Microsoft have decided to code the tool like this, but yes, it's because it's a Web Site. Probably because Web Sites don't have project files, or some such stupid reason. =)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Microsoft does not allow to do it using the standard method. I'm know [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper) allows this, but installing a big plugin for this is a bad idea. I think I have sinse found a small plugin which allows show or hide the full path. I am sure this should exist.